# Netty receiving multipart/related message gives unexpected character in prolog - instead of <

Tags: netty

I try to receive the following message with Netty 4.0, but keep getting unexpected character in prolog.

The message is as follows:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="-=Part.0.18fc51f6-a22b-4759-b186-5fa473d479c4=-"; type="text/xml"; start="<0>"; start-info="text/xml"

---=Part.0.1e843708-4576-408e-be3a-f33185bff722=-
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-ID: <0>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:eb="http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ebxml-msg/schema/msg-header-2_0.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <soap:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="2.0" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:osb:oin">00000003273229750000</eb:PartyId>
                <eb:Role>BevoegdGezag</eb:Role>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:osb:oin">00000005123456782000_OTA</eb:PartyId>
                <eb:Role>LVO</eb:Role>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>CPAID_ST_OLO_0312_SSL</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>67643250</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="urn:osb:services">LVO:2:0:0:I</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>Fo01</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>67643250@soapuimockserver</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2017-10-14T07:54:08Z</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:TimeToLive>2017-10-15T10:54:09Z</eb:TimeToLive>
            </eb:MessageData>
            <eb:DuplicateElimination/>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <eb:AckRequested eb:signed="false" eb:version="2.0" soap:actor="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-msg:actor:toPartyMSH" soap:mustUnderstand="1"/>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <eb:Manifest eb:version="2.0">
            <eb:Reference xlink:href="cid:1" xlink:type="simple"/>
        </eb:Manifest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
---=Part.0.1e843708-4576-408e-be3a-f33185bff722=-
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <1>

<StUF:Fo01Bericht xmlns:StUF="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301" xmlns:BG="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310" xmlns:LVO="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/lvo/0311" xmlns:smil20="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" xmlns:ZKN="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:smil20lang="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301 lvo0311msg.xsd">
         <StUF:stuurgegevens>
            <StUF:berichtcode>Fo01</StUF:berichtcode>
            <StUF:zender>
               <StUF:applicatie>SquitXO</StUF:applicatie>
            </StUF:zender>
            <StUF:ontvanger>
               <StUF:applicatie>OLO</StUF:applicatie>
            </StUF:ontvanger>
            <StUF:referentienummer>67643250</StUF:referentienummer>
            <StUF:tijdstipBericht>2017101409540300</StUF:tijdstipBericht>
            <StUF:crossRefnummer>456</StUF:crossRefnummer>
         </StUF:stuurgegevens>
         <StUF:body>
            <StUF:code>code0</StUF:code>
            <StUF:plek>client</StUF:plek>
            <StUF:omschrijving>omschrijving0</StUF:omschrijving>
         </StUF:body>
      </StUF:Fo01Bericht>
---=Part.0.1e843708-4576-408e-be3a-f33185bff722=---
```

Message with only a soap envelope go well however.

My setup looked like this until now.

```
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();

    if (sslCtx != null) {
        p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
    }

    p.addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder());
    p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(4*1024*1024));

    p.addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder());

    if(isCompressionDesired) {
        p.addLast(new HttpContentCompressor(7));
    }

    p.addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 60));

    if( isAdmin ) {
        p.addLast(new SnappyMockServerAdminHandler());
    }
    else {
        p.addLast(new SnappyMockServerSimpleHandler());
    }
}
```

I understand for multipart message to work something needs to be done with HttpPostRequestDecoder, but I can't find out how to fit this in.

The HttpPostRequestDecoder seems not happily getting along with HttpRequestDecoder/HttpObjectAggregator since they seem to contradict each other.

Any ideas how to get this going ?

Answer (score 0):

> The HttpPostRequestDecoder seems not happily getting along with HttpRequestDecoder/HttpObjectAggregator since they seem to contradict each other.

That's right the `HttpObjectAggregator` aggregates a HttpMessage and all its HttpContents into a single FullHttpRequest which is what you don't want when using a `HttpPostRequestDecoder`. ([Here is an example from netty's github on how to use the HttpPostRequestDecoder](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/upload/HttpUploadServerHandler.java))

By doing something like this it should work:

```
public void initChannel(Channel channel) {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();

    if (sslCtx != null)
        pipeline.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));

    pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());

    if(isCompressionDesired)
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpContentCompressor(7));

    pipeline.addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 60))
        .addLast(isAdmin ? new SnappyMockServerAdminHandler() : new SnappyMockServerSimpleHandler());
}
```